# JWT + IONIC 3 and Laravel 5.4 issue

Tags: laravel, ionic2, jwt, ionic3

Hi there I'm trying to migrate a Ionic 1 + Laravel 5.3 app to Ionic 3 but I have some trouble with JWT token based authorization.

I'm able to get the token from server but also
got this error:

[image]

Comment: thks changed title to be more detailed

Comment: judging by the error you are receiving, it looks like if you are getting something different than a fully well formated JWT.

Comment: yes. I have solved. The API returning also the user detail

Answer (score 0):

I have solved. The API return array of token and user detail. Need to parse this string as well now